# Transform a fan page into a Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I have a fan page and would like to change it into a group without losing my fans and retaining my videos and pictures.

Is it possible to transform a Facebook fan page into a group?

Comment: No. That's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to convert a page into a group or the reverse. Below is the quote from the Group -> Page help on Facebook and gives good advice on how to do it manually.

According to this [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=174453762608867)

> It is currently not possible to convert Facebook groups into Pages. We recommend that you create a Page and notify your group members about it. Note that you will not be able to send your group a message if your group has more than 5,000 members.

Comment: I believe he's asking about the opposite of that, i.e. page -> group.

Comment: You're totally right. I read that page wrong, but it's still not possible even if I can't find a source for it. Updating my answer.